# Make focus stacking work faster in Python

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to run tufuse from python using subprocess.call to merge several layers of images and create one focus stack image. The input images are huge and take 20 min on my PC (12 cores, 64 G RAM) to do the job. I want to use multiprocessing or multi-threading or GPU computation to reduce this time. However none of the solutions I tried did work. As far as I understood these methods work on algebraic functions not with subprocess.call. Do you have any idea how to make this task runs faster?

Comment: In general you can't run a program intended for a cpu on a gpu(I mean you could translate or emulate it our something but that will likely not work) if tufuse only uses one core/thread you can try doing multiple tufuse processes at once.

Comment: If you have several images, you can run the command in parallel. If this is not fast enough, you could rewrite a faster implementation, but this require programming skill (there is no free lunch). Anyway, you need to be more specific on what you exactly want so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I asked my updated question in a new post. I will really appreciate it if you can help there. I also provided the input images and my code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188852/python-subprocess-mix-up-the-output-of-different-processes).